# How to do git status from powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I tried this and it doesn't show any output. What is the right way to do this?

```
invoke-expression 'git status'
```

Comment: you only need to be on the git directory something like `C:\path\to\git_repositories\git_repo_1>git status`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install-Module posh-git -Scope AllUsers
2. Import-Module posh-git
3. CD in Powershell to any cloned Git repo folder and the prompt itself gives you the full status

More info:

```
 https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git
```

Otherwise, you can always fall back on the standard Git shell with a "git status" but issuing an invoke-expression etc. in PS for the non-PS CIM is certainly not the most efficient way to work with Git locally in PS.